Node JS Load test for CPU bounded tasks and IO bounded tasks giving same results
We know that NodeJS is good at handling networks and non-blocking I/O. I created three APIs:

One with a constant amount of time, 
one with a CPU-bounded task and 
another with a network call.

In the first case, I ran API 1 and API 2 at the same time. In the second case, I run API 1 and API 3.
Why is the average response time for API 1 almost similar in both cases? I am expecting a shorter response time for a network call.
app.get("/fast", (req, res) => {
  res.send("I am fast");
});

app.get("/cpu", (req, res) => {
  const start = Date.now();
  while (Date.now() - start < 5000) { }
  res.send("I took 5 seconds");
});

app.get("/io", (req, res) => {
  axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2')
  .then(function (response) {
    res.send("Network call success");
  })
});



These are my Jmeter test results
/fast and  /cpu APIs are  executed  in parallel
/fast and  /io APIs are  executed  in parallel
My Computer spec:
AMD Ryzen 5 3400G with Radeon Vega Graphics  3.70 GHz
RAM:8GB

I think we miss your test setup to understand the issue better. What software do you use for the benchmark? What is the spec of the computer?

For instance, does the benchmark run calls one by one ? Does it do sequentially /fast /cpu /fast ?

/fast and /cpu APIs are executed in parallel ./fast and /io APIs are executed in parallel
My Computer spec: AMD Ryzen 5 3400G with Radeon Vega Graphics 3.70 GHz RAM:8GB

Do you send /fast requests one by one or all at the same time ? Do you know if your web server uses several cores?
